# WORDPRESS - How to manage code repository with GIT

Tags: wordpress, git

In wordpress development, we have to deal with upgrade version of plugins and I don't know how to manage code repository with them. actually, we have 3 folders like wp-content, wp-admin, wp-includes, ...

- Should I push all of the code which belong to wordpress folder into the GIT repository? Then the new version of plugin will affect to changes of files.
- How do I manage the changing of files as less as it can? Should I use .gitignore for it?

Updated: I found the solution at here with the examples. Check this [link](https://deliciousbrains.com/using-composer-manage-wordpress-themes-plugins/) out 
.It is really cool

Comment: You may use some combination of manual selection of files and `.gitignore`.  Binary files, such as large images and/or media files, probably should not be included in your Git repo.  Maybe small images like icons are OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress can be a joy for running in a GIT repository, this is how I handle it.

I gitignore wp-config.php because that is usually different between local, staging and live sites.

I also gitignore the uploads folder because binary files in git suck and your repo will grow brutally fast. Plus it makes it a pain in the butt to do local development while the site is live.

There are some cool solutions out there, search for Bedrock by Roots for doing interesting deploys, but honestly the simplest way is just to make a repo of the entire install minus the uploads and wp-config.php.

Manually create the wp-config.php on the server.
Use rsync to manage the uploads or you could use FTP if you're not keen on the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

This is the .gitignore file that I use for my projects.

```
/.idea/
*.log
/wp-includes/
/wp-admin/
/wp-content/advanced-cache.php
/wp-content/backup-db/
/wp-content/backups/
/wp-content/cache/
/wp-content/languages/
/wp-content/plugins/
/wp-content/upgrade/
/wp-content/uploads/
/wp-content/wflogs/
/wp-content/wp-cache-config.php
/.htaccess
/license.txt
/readme.html
```

I only work with private repositories so I don't have to exclude the wp-config.php.

Comment: Adding caching folders is a good idea, forgot about that. I find it a bit odd that your wp-config is the same locally as it is on your different servers though, and since .env isn't in that list I assume you aren't using that.

Comment: I always use a check like this(within wp-config.php): `if( stripos( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.devdomain.nl' ) !== false ) { // Execute whatever for development domain } else { // Execute whatever for live domain }` in order to check what database variables I need to define. This is also usefull to define variables like `define( 'IS_DEV_DOMAIN', true );`. `IS_DEV_DOMAIN` can be used to not execute things like analytics on the development domain.